# Why is there no initiallyDeferred parameter on Liquibase addNotNullConstraint?

Tags: liquibase

Any reason why Liquibase's [addNotNullConstraint](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_not_null_constraint.html) doesn't have an attribute `initiallyDeferred`?

[addForeignKeyConstraint](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_foreign_key_constraint.html) and [addUniqueConstraint](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_unique_constraint.html) both have an attribute `initiallyDeferred`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a missing feature. Liquibase has very few people contributing code, so sometimes things just aren't done yet. My company (Datical) has been making efforts to improve that, but we still rely very heavily on the users of Liquibase to point out where there are shortcomings.

I have created a jira ticket ([CORE-3024](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3024)) to track this.